# In PHP move_uploaded_file() to upload files in other system in localhost

Tags: php, soap-client

i need to upload my uploaded files in other system.i have use the below code.but it shows error:

*PHP Warning :move_uploaded_file(
http: //ipaddress/newDesign/documents_upload/test assignment.pdf) failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections*

```
$baseUrl = 'http://192.168.1.11/newDesign';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],$baseUrl.'/documents_upload/'.$name);
```

how to move uploaded files to the destination folder which is in other system.i have connected through SoapRequest.

Comment: Map a local drive to a remove drive and save to the local drive. You can't just expect PHP to be able to upload to any IP that you specify.

Comment: move_uploaded_file expects file name, not URL as second parameter. You need to break your action into two pieces: getting uploaded file and sending uploaded file somewhere